# TypeScript generic function creating new instance with parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, interface

I have many classes extending an interface. These classes can have arrays containg objects of each other. So for instance: A school can contain many studens but both implements the same interface.

I've create a generic function for this instead of using every time a forEach loop and pushing them to the array. This new generic function should do this for me with a single line.

```
export class School implements MyInterface {
    public studens: Student[] = [];
    public constructor(data_from_backend) {
        this.students = mapDataToModelArrayFunction<Student>(data_from_backend.students);
    }
}

export class Student implements MyInterface {
    public name: string;
    public constructor(data_from_backend) {
        this.name = data_from_backend.name;
    }
}

export function mapDataToModelArrayFunction<T>(array): T[] {
    const listToReturn: T[] = [];
    if (Array.isArray(array)) {
        array.forEach(item => {
            listToReturn.push(new T(obj));
        });
    }
    return listToReturn;
}
```

But TypeScript/Angular is giving me an error because of the T. I'm not allowed to create an instance of T. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types do not exist at runtime so `T` is erased and the expression `new T(item)` turns into `new (item)` which does not really make sense. Or another way of saying this, you can't use types in expressions.

The solution is to pass in a constructor function (ie the class) into your mapping function:

```
interface MyInterface { }
export class School implements MyInterface {
    public students: Student[] = [];
    public constructor(data_from_backend: any) {
        this.students = mapDataToModelArrayFunction(Student, data_from_backend.students);
    }
}

export class Student implements MyInterface {
    public name: string;
    public constructor(data_from_backend: any) {
        this.name = data_from_backend.name;
    }
}

export function mapDataToModelArrayFunction<T>(cls: new (data: any) => T, array: any[]): T[] {
    const listToReturn: T[] = [];
    if (Array.isArray(array)) {
        array.forEach(item => {
            listToReturn.push(new cls(item));
        });
    }
    return listToReturn;
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5rycgb2QF8AoCADwAcB7KMZBAGzgGdXkBlBACxpqbJgAWypMIwiOA4ZskWIhQFSyVcioBXAEZNgCZKzAaAJlLCsAXFyOnwAbQC6yALzJHAbhVrNOvYxoghlAaCGB0ABTGcGBwAPowUDTCsVqIANZSxlZwIOgAlIReampgPMCsAHSGJmYcrsJwVAAi0XAAKjSoNKZMAIJQUHDoAGIaIKHAAeGcNmYANMhRMfGJyakIGSDGVbPSeZ7FZGTk1HQMzGwcMzXgQqLiktJoWDgK+MrFPrr6IHCSVkFQABzA7ebTffyBMDBUIRJZxBJJFLpTLZXIFD7FEplSq-SQuRatFZI9abbZ4iCg1RHUgnWj0ZAwMYTALIBrNVodLo9fqDEbMsCTEAAHjaAD5wsxLMgQBAAO7ISKtNH5Fxi5BtBZwAZDFWOPJWNqOQrFBABQzIXSGDoAJQgRigIENxtcHiKQhgit5Qwq5W96HC2r5eQx7uKQZ9MDoAFFEDxwsBIMI1SasWmrWBbfaNI6KppWPHZQqpQmkyGqVjiPt3WRilBs47LeVMzQ7Q6QJ5iEA)